# CWWKS1100A: Authentication did not succeed for user ID Admin_MobileFirst_Server_Config

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Setup:

MobileFirst server 8.0 on Liberty Farm 8.5.5
IBM DB2
IBM MF Analytics

The MF server is configured as MobileFirst_Server_Config using server configuration tool. and when i see in server.xml, it creates some inbuilt users automatically with their password like Admin_MobileFirst_Server_Config or Push_MobileFirst_Server_Config.

i get below error more frequently in the websphere logs. we never changed anything related to this inbuilt users.

> y.authentication.jaas.modules.UsernameAndPasswordLoginModule A CWWKS1100A: Authentication did not succeed for user ID Admin_MobileFirst_Server_Config. An invalid user ID or password was specified.

Can anyone help me to understand what causes this error and resolution if any.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe because of the hostname specified in the server.xml for authorization URL and push URLs. If the URL consists of localhost change that value to the machine IP address and restart the server.